# videoUiKit-ios.git could not be resolved

Tags: agora.io

because VideoUIKit-iOS >=1.5.1 contains incompatible tools version and root depends on VideoUIKit-iOS 4.1.1..<5.0.0, version solving failed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJDpO.png)

i changed the version to lowest they ask no version found